# nginx slower than apache2

Tags: nginx, performance, php-fpm

I migrate my nextcloud-instance from apache2 to nginx and I hoped that is faster than apache, but it isn't. We've around 30requests/s on this page.

With apache2 I've 160req/s and with nginx I got 45req/s tested with

```
ab -n 5000 -c 500
```

We've 4core and 16GB RAM, my php-fpm config looks like:

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 700
pm.start_servers = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 80
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

Comment: enable caching for nginx may benefit your performance

Comment: we switched back to apache with mod-php, this don't eat my CPU and it respond much faster

Comment: ok, i run nginx as reverseproxy infront of 10 containers without any penalty? strange behavior